# Fire a JS function every time a settings flyout appears

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I currently need a couple JavaScript functions to fire every time a user pulls out a settings flyout to dynamically populate the flyout. For example:

```
(function() { 
    functionOne();
})();

functionOne() {
    //Do setuptasks        
}
```

The functions will fire once, at first load of the flyout, but once the flyout is dismissed, its DOM elements are destroyed and must be repopulated when it is reloaded. However, the above code will run only once, at first launch of the flyout, then persist. Re-launching the flyout does not cause the above script block to fire again.

Does the settings flyout trigger any events that I could add an event listener for to handle when the settings flyout launches and/or dismisses?

Comment: No but you could trigger a custom event http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: I would still need that custom event to fire whenever the settings flyout activates. I've tried the custom event approach, and will still only trigger once, then never again since the script perceives itself as still active, even after settings flyout has been dismissed.

I could try to add a variety of listeners for when the user tries the various ways to dismiss the page, but is not an ideal solution, and can see it semantically breaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at:

- onafterhide
- onaftershow
- onbeforehide
- onbeforeshow

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701253.aspx

Comment: How did I miss this?! Grr, I was looking for exactly this and was staring me in the face the whole time. Going to try this out when I get home and mark this as correct answer when it works.

Comment: Yep, this solved it for me. Again, cannot believe I missed this as I was exactly looking for the events fired when a settings flyout is activated. Thank you daughtkom!

Comment: No problem.  If I had a dollar for every time someone pointed out something that I had overlooked, I'd have a lot of dollars...

Answer (score 0):

Set your settings flyout to be a page ex /pages/settings/settings.html, and that page has a defined ready function - just like you would do with a typical navigation page.

```
WinJS.Pages.define('/pages/settings/settings/html', {
ready: function(element, options)
 { 
   //do your init here
 }
});
```

and in your app's code to initialize the flyout:

```
app.onsettings = function (e) {
   e.detail.applicationcommands = {
                 preferencesDiv: { title: "Preferences", 
                 href: "/pages/settings/settings.html" }
                                  }
                               };
```

This will be called every time the settings are loaded. Note we are talking after an item is selected in the settings charm, not the population of the charm itself which happens when you register your handlers.